# Document-based application icon

Tags: cocoa, icons, document-based

there is something strange with icon of my document in cocoa. In Target - Info - Document Types, I set up png icon which is 512 x 512. When I run my application, save my document, there is white icon on my document, not which i set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your PNG file might not have a properly premultiplied alpha channel. How was it generated?

Comment: I user Sketch application for Mac

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your Xcode settings and how the icon looks on your desktop?